# Change of IP / Configure AirPort Extreme

Tags: network, wifi, airport, time-capsule, dns

Earlier today our IP Address changed due to misconfiguration caused by our ISP. I'm trying to ensure our IP won't change again. So I spoke with our ISP and they assigned us a static IP (we were supposed to already have one).

I'm trying to ensure everything will work once I change the AirPort IP settings. We're currently running DHCP, but I believe we would need to switch to static, correct?

Our network is configured as follows:

Internet >-ethernet-> AirPort Extreme >-wifi-> Time Capsule

We have 6 iMacs that connect through wifi to our AirPort Extreme

Our Mac Mini Server connects through ethernet to our AirPort Extreme

Our Mac Mini Server serves example.com for File Sharing and other services outside of the office

Our Time Capsule connects through wifi to our Mac Mini Server

It would also be great to know exactly where each number needs to go:

Static IP: 11.111.111.111

Gateway: 22.222.222.222

Subnet Mask: 333.333.333.333

Primary DNS: 44.444.44.44

Secondary DNS: 55.555.55.55

Answer (score 1):

The WAN (the outside of your router) connection in the router (your AirPort) should be set to static if your ISP provide the information about IP, gateway, subnet-mask and DNS. Some ISP assign static IP remotely so you don't have and can continue using DHCP. It's all about what they tell you to do.

Your local computers should not need to change anything as the router translate all traffic from them to be displayed online as your static IP.

When it comes to the different numbers and where they are suppose to go it should be clear in the information from the ISP.